# How to force terminate all workers in ThreadPoolExecutor immediately

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have a number of tasks inside a `TheadPoolExecutor`. I have a stop button on my interface that should terminate all the threads inside `ThreadPoolExecutor` immediately. I am looking for a way to do it. (without `shutDown()` or `shutDownNow()`).

Thanks

Comment: Why don't (or can't) you use `shtudown()` or `shutdownNow()`?  That's the way to do it.

Comment: Because it must wait for the current tasks to finish before terminating the threads. So, it does not kill the threads immediately.

Comment: `shutdown()` waits for the current tasks to finish.  That's the point of it.

Comment: @Gray I want the current and the remaining tasks to be abandoned immediately. Am I making any sense?

Comment: In your question you state `terminate all the threads inside ThreadPoolExecutor immediately` but now in the comment you say `wait for the current tasks to finish before terminating the threads`. Which is it ?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I don't want it to wait. I am looking for a method to terminate the jobs in the threadpool without waiting at all.

Comment: there's ambiguity in @dlock 's first response (2nd comment).  dlock used the first "it" to refer to ThreadPoolExecutor, and the second "it" to refer to Java.  so, to dlock second question (4th comment) - "it" does not make sense with pronouns but "it" would make sense if the pronouns were replaced with nouns.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot safely kill threads immediately. You tasks should instead honour interrupts and stop when interrupted. If you use `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()`, all the running tasks will be interrupted.

The only alternative is to the threads in a separate process is issue a signal to kill the process.

Answer (score 7):

Old question but I think you can extend ThreadPoolExecutor to capture running Thread reference in beforeExecute().
When shutdownNow() would be called you can stop() all running Threads.
Although I would strongly encourage relying on isInterrupted() in your tasks.

Sample code ->

```
public class KillableThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private final Map<Runnable, Thread> executingThreads;

    public KillableThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, String threadNamePrefix) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, new YoungMemorySafeLinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), ThreadFactories.create(threadNamePrefix));
        executingThreads = new HashMap<>(maximumPoolSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        super.beforeExecute(t, r);
        executingThreads.put(r, t);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        if(executingThreads.containsKey(r)) {
            executingThreads.remove(r);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        List<Runnable> runnables = super.shutdownNow();
        for(Thread t : executingThreads.values()) {
            t.stop();
        }
        return runnables;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `shutdown()` will only make the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to reject all new submited tasks, and remove from the queue (if the `ThreadPool` is an unbounded queue executor) the pending tasks.
The `shutdownNow()` will do exactly the same, and also will call to the `interrupt()` method of the `Thread`. So, in your `run()` method, you should handle it properly:

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
   // Handle the exception, and close resources.
}
```

Comment: `shutdown()` does not empty the queue.

Comment: @The111 to empty the queue you can use purge()

Answer (score 3):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` is an `ExecutorService`. You can't stop all threads in `ExecutorService` either with `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` methods. You have to call `shutdown(), awaitTermination()` and `shutdownNow()` methods in a sequence for graceful shutdown as quoted by oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

Other options:

1. `invokeAll()`
2. `CountDownLatch`
3. Iterate through all `Future.get()` for all `Callable` tasks to achieve the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `Callable`s instead of `Runnable`s in your threads you could try and call [`someTask.cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) to get rid of the running tasks at the time of `shutdownNow()` call.

Note that I have not tried this, so I can not guarantee it would work like you would like to, but judging from the javadoc description it's worth a try.